# Get Memory Address of Binary Instructions

Tags: c++, winapi, exe, binaryfiles

I'm currently working on some system level code where I would like to be able to identify the memory section(s) that are from the loaded binary in order to detect things like corrupted or modified instructions;

Essentially what I'm after is a way, in Win32 using C++, to get a pointer to the range of instructions. This is somewhat similar to asking for a function pointer to the .text section's start and end. My understanding of the exe format is that the .text section is where instructions are stored, versus the .data section which holds things like global variables. Unfortunately I've found 0 hints on where this might be (I've seen no win32 function calls, nothing in the TIB, etc.)

Can anyone direct me to where I could find/calculate this information?

P.S. I do understand that if anyone changes code maliciously that they may find this code and change it; I'm still interested in the details of how to get at this information for my own curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the entry-point to your code in the PE header. Download the PE (Portable Executable) file definition from MSDN - it has all the information. The format of the program in memory is virtually the same as it is on disk. From within the code, you can get a pointer to the PE header in memory via the GetModuleHandle() function (the handle is really a pointer to the first page).

Comment: Another new piece of information. Hmm, do you know if a HANDLE is just a memory address to the first page what the purpose of making sure you always close the handle is? I'm assuming the OS must track how many times the page is opened separately, otherwise what is the point? Just curious here.

Comment: Generally, it does, but GetModuleHandle (as a special case) does not increment the handle's reference count.

Comment: You are talking about an HMODULE which is very different from a HANDLE.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really expect this to work with an in memory binary. Any function calls to imported DLLs will get modified by the loader to point to the actual locations of the target procedures in the DLL that is loaded.

For example suppose you call a function in kernel32.dll. Then a Windows update happens which changes kernel32.dll. The next time you run your app, the jump to the function in kernel32.dll is going to be to a different memory address than the before the Windows update was applied.

And of course this all assumes that DLLs load at their preferred address.  And then you may have some self-modifying code.

And so on, and so on.

Comment: Good points David, in fact one of the purposes of this was to detect if some self modifying code has occurred yet. I hadn't considered DLL loading altering this however... Hmm. Thanks, Learn something every day!

Comment: From some more reading I've done, actually, this seems incorrect. Based on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769(VS.60).aspx when you load a DLL it does not alter the actual DLL call, it is more akin to setting a function pointer which your application is calling.

Comment: But that's just it, the loaded code doesn't change according to this.

Comment: You didn't understand the article.

Comment: Please enlighten me then; this isn't a helpful comment. So long as the location of the function is stored in a function lookup table (e.g. Import Address Table) as data it is irrelevant if that data is changed at load time. Since I'm concerned with the binary instructions only, other data changes are irrelevant.

Comment: every call to an external location gets modified. That's what the article says. It's what I said.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try one last time to do this civilly. The article is quite clear -- you have a call to a given memory address -- call 0x4000000 to use their example. Nothing ever changes this address to some other address. Instead, data is placed at that address which is in turn a jump to the appropriate location. The actual functions in my application do not change, so the checksum over their contents will remain the same.

Comment: @tom that's not how it works and it's not what the article says

Comment: @Tom The jump is in your code. It jumps to code in another module. The destination is unknown at compile time. Therefore, it must be modified.

Comment: I am quoting here: "In 32-bit environments, the linker generates a thunk of which it does know the address. The thunk looks like:
   0x40000000:    jmp DWORD PTR __imp_func1
Here __imp_func1 is the address for func1's slot in the import address table of the .EXE file [...] The loader only has to update the .EXE file's import address table at load time for everything to work correctly." -- from the reading of this it is very clearly dereferencing a pointer which is set at load time. There is no run time modification of the code, only what that pointer is set to.

Comment: ...Uh, yes, load time being part of run time not my point of contention. My point of contention is that the instructions are not being modified. It's a function pointer, it's being set. The call isn't "inlined" into the code, it's put into the import address table.

Comment: @Tom the import address table is part of your module! If it wasn't, how would the JMP instruction be read?

Comment: @Tom Anyway, you clearly disagree with me. You have one view, I have another. I think we can leave it at that.

Comment: Okay, let's see if this rephrasing makes it any clearer: I want to run a checksum over the INSTRUCTIONS in my binary (the .text section of the EXE format). The whole reason I can't checksum over the whole application space is to not have the very problem you've pointed out. If the loader actually went into the instructions one by one and corrected them (the method used in 16bit exes) I would be screwed, but based on some experimentation and the documentation I'm not -- I still don't have a good way to get the start/end point of these in memory which is my original query. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but for your overall solution, you could look into [Code Signing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing).  If you like this solution, there are existing implementations on Windows.

As you said, binary verification alone won't solve your problem.  You should also look into installing your application in an area of the file system that requires elevation/admin rights to write to, such as Program Files, or deploy it somewhere a user can't directly modify it, like a web server.